# Emacs C++, opening corresponding header file

Tags: c++, c, emacs

I am new to emacs and I was wondering

- if there is a shortcut to switch between header/source and the corresponding source/header file
- if there is a reference card like the general emacs ref card

Thanks !

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There's `ff-find-other-file`.

You can bind this to your own key using something like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-o") 'ff-find-other-file)
```

But of course you'll need to pick a key that doesn't already have something useful bound to it :)

Comment: I think that, if possible, you should prefer making your own keybindings of the form `"C-c <letter>"`, with the second keystroke not being paired with a CTRL char. I remember reading when first starting emacs that there had just recently (in emacs time) been a massive re-structuring of the shortcuts that existed specifically to reserve this namespace for user bindings. `"C-x C-*"` is likely to be used by a major mode or by emacs itself. For example, `"C-x C-o"` is taken by `(delete-blank-lines)` by default in my install.

Comment: I should have read the rest of the answers: mloskot's answer below follows keybinding best practices, emacs users should usually do that kind of thing, unless they really want something to be global.

Comment: What do you do if your files are `.cpp` and `.h`? this seems not to find the file

Comment: (defvar my-cpp-other-file-alist '(("\\.cpp\\'" (".h")) ("\\.h\\'" (".cpp"))))
(setq-default ff-other-file-alist 'my-cpp-other-file-alist)
do the above, and then follow the instructions posted above. if you want to extend to more pairs, just add to my-cpp-other-file-alist.

Answer (score 24):

Check the excellent Emacs-fu article [Quickly switching between header and implementation](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2008/12/quickly-switching-between-header-and.html)

In case the blog post has gone, here is copy of the solution:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda() 
    (local-set-key  (kbd "C-c o") 'ff-find-other-file)))
```

> Now, we can quickly switch between myfile.cc and myfile.h with C-c o.
>   Note the use of the c-mode-common-hook, so it will work
>   for both C and C++.

Comment: `ff-find-other-file` prompts me for a location where the header file might be located, which is precisely what I want the function to do for me. My header files are often in this kind of location, in relation to the source I am currently in: `../../inc/mydir`. As in, source file is `src/mydir/file.cpp`, and header is `inc/mydir/file.hpp`. Would you expect `ff-find-other-file` to work automagically in this case too?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using eassist package from CEDET contrib, and it has eassist-switch-h-cpp function to do this taks

Comment: Do you know if it does something that the other option (see other answer) doesn't ?