# emacs: Automatically open corresponding file in another instance

Tags: c++, emacs

I want something similar to [Emacs C++, opening corresponding header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509919/emacs-c-opening-corresponding-header-file) except that I want to

1) *Always* automatically open the corresponding header; and

2) Do that in another emacs instance (if someone came up with a solution that made all other emacs instances do this, it would be fine also.)

Note that I use emacs in the terminal mode so I can't do https://superuser.com/questions/102163/how-to-split-emacs-over-a-dual-monitor (or at least I do not know how).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution to 2) is to run an emacs instance with
`server-mode` enabled in the second terminal and command it from the
main emacs instance by using `server-eval-at`.

To launch the slave, run:

```
$ emacs --eval '(progn (setq server-name "ff-slave") (server-mode 1))'
```

Then use the following code to command it:

```
(require 'server)
(require 'find-file)

(defun command-ff-slave ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((b (ff-other-file-name)))
      (if (null b)
          (message "Found no other file")
          (server-eval-at "ff-slave"
                          `(find-file ,b))))))
```

Calling `command-ff-slave` from the main emacs instance
should open any related file in a new buffer on the slave server.

Comment: Great answer. I ended up doing essentially this.

Comment: The code isn't very robust, though, and may need some additional tweaking.